# insert one-many relationship using SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Please let me know how to insert one-many relationship in a single query.
I have table A (aId,name,surname) table B (bId, street, pincode,aId)

Comment: This looks like it will likely require some special SQL. What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle? Do you know what version(s) of them you need to support?

Comment: i am using SQLite DB personal edition 3.4

Answer (score 2):

You don't.  This is why [transactions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) exist.  You start a transaction, submit all your queries, and then commit the transaction.  The database goes from one state where none of the queries are completed to a state where all of the queries are completed.  There is no in between state to worry about.  Transactions are how RDBMSs implement the [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) component of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID).

Comment: is it possible if i try like insert into TableB values('','','select aid from Table a where aid=2')

Comment: If you know aid is 2, you wouldn't need to do the query in question. I'm not familiar with SQLite myself, but in other RDBMS's you can do something like
INSERT INTO TableB (a, b, c, d)
  SELECT 1 AS a, 2 AS b, 'Something AS c, AID as d
  FROM TableA
  WHERE somecondition = 1;

Comment: I don't think that will work.  Generally if you want to use a `SELECT` statement in an `INSERT` you use the [defined](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) method: `INSERT INTO TableA (Id, ...) SELECT X, Y, Z, ... FROM TableB`